# How to stop brush drag when mouse leaves the chart area

Tags: echarts

The issue is this:

- left-click in the chart area and HOLD the left button
- now the brush-drag is active: we can move the mouse around and the area will follow
- but when we exit the chart area (e.g. far to the right on the grey area) and then release the mouse button (still on the grey area), the brush-drag mode gets stuck

  - what I mean is, when you now move the mouse back to the chart area, the brush-drag is still active: i.e. the mouse move will resize the brush area although the left-mouse button is NOT pressed down anymore
  - this will only stop when you make another click inside the chart area

[image: gif - brush-drag is stuck]

How can we avoid this?

- what I want to happen is that the brush area just selects all the data (until the border of the chart) and then stops: i.e. it should do the same as when I release the mouse button in the chart
- So I thought I can just send a mouseup event when the mouse leaves the chart area - but this does not work
- I also did not find a suitable [action](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action) in the echart-docs

Here is a full [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tmtron/kdaqhpjv/92/) and the `mouseup` event that I tried to send:

```
  const mouseUpEvent = new MouseEvent('mouseup');
  var echartsDom = myChart.getDom();
  var canceled = echartsDom.dispatchEvent(mouseUpEvent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug [echarts#10675](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/10675) that has been fixed in version 4.5.0